# i want to use VM like a Localhost Serve

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I'm writing now from Ubuntu Desktop 17.10
and I installed VirtualBox 5.1 from Ubuntu repository, 
then created new VM with Ubuntu Server 16.4 to use it as web server..
so I have Ubuntu Server 16.4 with ssh and Apache2 IN VM.

From "VirtualBox - Preferences => Network" I added new Host-Only Networks, it's named "vboxnet0"

[image: Screen shot]

and from "VM Settings => Network" I Chose:

- "Nat" as "Adapter 1" and checked to Cable Connected,
- "Host-Only Adapter" as "Adapter 2" and selected "vboxnet0"  with "Promiscuous Mode: Allow All".

modified `etc/network/interfaces` like this:

[image: like that (screenshot)]

`ifconfig -a` shows:

[image: Screenshot]

and I disabled firewall.

but when i try to connect from desktop to vm using SSH this message shows:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.101 port 22: No route to host
```

and i can't access to web server from desktop "http://192.168.56.101/" gives me:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

I want to use VM like a Localhost Server, what's my mistake or what am I missing ?

Answer (score 4):

When you use the Host-Only network on VirtualBox (or VMware), you're basically **isolating your virtual machines into a same network that is inaccessible from other networks** (because a Host-Only network doesn't have a gateway). So, to be able to do a routing between networks, you'll need to use the NAT network. This type of network is separated from your *real* network but it can still be routed because it's on the routing table of your computer. Think of a NAT network as a Host-Only that can be routed from your own computer.

[image: As you can see, the Host-Only network can't be reached directly from your host, but the NAT network VMs can be routed to your host.]
As you can see, the Host-Only network can't be reached directly from your host, but the NAT network VMs can be routed to your host.

Once you've put your VM on NAT, make sure you've put a gateway in */etc/network/interfaces*. For example:

```
 auto enp0s8
    iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.56.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.56.1
```

(Image source: https://www.eandbsoftware.org/networking-between-host-and-guest-vms-host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 0):

im founded what i missing,

just i miss to check to [Cable Connected] for "Adapter 2".

now i can access to VM server.